# Upgrading storybook from 6.3.7 to 6.4.22 shows spinner and no stories in react/typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I have the project configured with CRA and I updating the packages to the following in package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.22",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "chromatic": "^6.5.4",
  },
```

and my main.tsx looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/introduction.stories.tsx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ]
}
```

But all I get is a spinner loading and no stories: [image: screenshot]

I didn't upgrade storybook the traditional way of `npx sb upgrade` I did it package by package for some reason, don't ask me why?

Any idea's anyone?

Any idea's? no errors in console either.

Comment: No errors in console believe it or not, that's why I am confused but I just read now that version 6 is a major version change, which I did not read before doing the upgrade

Comment: _"no errors in console either"_... are you totally sure? Make sure you haven't filtered out any log levels. What about in your terminal where you run StoryBook?

Comment: I get the message storybook 6.4.22 for react started and then the regular links to the environment, But I am using typescript and I read something about Zero config typescript now

Comment: Did you check your browser console log levels? In Chrome, it's a dropdown to the right of the _Filter_ textbox. I mean, it's probably not that but you'll kick yourself if you'd accidentally disabled _Errors_

Comment: Yep errors in ticked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out don't upgrade the packages individually, the best thing to do is:

```
npx sb@latest upgrade
```

once I did this, after reverting to a previous commit, It all worked as expected.